# Can't use the input from the MouseListener

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
public class Viewer implements MouseListener
{
  static int counter = 0;
  static double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    JFrame outerFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setSize(400,400);
    outerFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    outerFrame.setTitle("Drawing Triangle");
    outerFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    outerFrame.add(panel);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(counter == 0) {
          x1 = e.getX();
          y1 = e.getY();

        } else if(counter == 1) {
          x2 = e.getX();
          y2 = e.getY();

        } else if(counter == 2) {
          x3 = e.getX();
          y3 = e.getY();

        }

        counter++;
      }

    });
    System.out.println(x2);
    System.out.println(y2);
    System.out.println(x1);
    System.out.println(y1);    
    System.out.println(x3);
    System.out.println(y3);

    TriangleComponent component = new TriangleComponent(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);

    outerFrame.add(component);
    outerFrame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

I am trying to use users mouse input to make them draw a triangle. I also have a trianglecomponent class as well as a constructor that uses the xs and ys here.So I used the println's at the end and saw that code runs before xs and ys. How can I change this to get the xs and ys from the mouse before drawing anything

Comment: You can't create that component before the user actually presses the mouse the third time. That's why GUI systems are *event driven*. You will have to construct it when you get the third click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the drawing part of the event handling so move everything after the listener into the listener so the you draw the triangle right after you read the third click.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating the `TriangleComponent` before knowing where to draw it (x1, x2, y1, ecc...).

To solve this, simply create the `TriangleComponent` after you have all the coordinates (after the third click):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
public class Viewer implements MouseListener
{
  static int counter = 0;
  static double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    final JFrame outerFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setSize(400,400);
    outerFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    outerFrame.setTitle("Drawing Triangle");
    outerFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    outerFrame.add(panel);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(counter == 0) {
          x1 = e.getX();
          y1 = e.getY();

        } else if(counter == 1) {
          x2 = e.getX();
          y2 = e.getY();

        } else if(counter == 2) {
          x3 = e.getX();
          y3 = e.getY();

          TriangleComponent component = new TriangleComponent(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);

          outerFrame.add(component);

          System.out.println(x2);
          System.out.println(y2);
          System.out.println(x1);
          System.out.println(y1);    
          System.out.println(x3);
          System.out.println(y3);
        }

        counter++;
      }

    });

    panel.setFocusable(true);

    outerFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: local variable outerFrame is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: If you put the frame's `setVisible` in the event handler, you're not going to have a frame in which to click the mouse.